# Connect Docker Containers with remote debugger

Tags: docker, remote-debugging, docker-machine, jconsole, jvisualvm

I am trying to connect my docker containers with JConsole or JVisualVM.
There are some articles I googled like
http://www.jamasoftware.com/blog/monitoring-java-applications/
but that didn't work for me.

How can I connect them to my running container. **I am using latest docker for mac, So I don't have docker machine for ip *192.168.99.100***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost` along with the other rmi/jmx parameters.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=9090
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9090 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost
```